# .then() is executed before nested promise.all and fetch are done

Tags: javascript, json, api, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to create an app that retrieves data from an API using fetch in Javascript. Here's the JSON structure for a couple of urls

myapi.com/list  returns:
[{id:111, user:nam1},{id:222, user:nam2}]
Then I have to do another request with one of these id
example: myapi.com/list/111 returns:

```
[{id:111,user:name1,description: "some text",public:true}]
```

example: myapi.com/list/111/posts returns:

```
[{a1:"some data",a2:"some data2"},{b1:"some data",b2:"some data2"},{c1:"some data",c2:"some data2"}]
```

for a couple of reasons I need to create a function that returns 1 array grouping all of these in the following format:

```
   [
    {id:111,user:name1,description: "some text",public:true, 
    posts:[{a1:"some data",a2:"some data2"},{b1:"some data",b2:"some data2"},{c1:"some data",c2:"some data2"}]
    },
    {id:222,user:name2,description: "some text2",public:true
    posts:[{a1:"some data",a2:"some data2"},{b1:"some data",b2:"some data2"},{c1:"some data",c2:"some data2"}
    }
    ]
```

Here's my main program
This works fine due to the setTimeOut:

```
    Promise.all([FetchFunctionThatworks(),FetchfunctionWithPrblm() ])
    .then(values => new State(values[0], values[1]))
    .then(state => {console.log(state) ; 

      setTimeout(function(){
      functionA(state); // a function that prints some html with the result of the FetchfunctionWithPrblm

  },200)
   ;} )
    .catch(reason => console.error(reason));
```

I wish to remove the setTimeout but the problem is that my code inside the .then() calls functionA before the promise is resolved so the structure I get is missing the "posts", with the setTimeOut I get the desired output.

Here's the my FetchfunctionWithPrblm()

```
function FetchfunctionWithPrblm() {
  const url = serverUrl+ "list/";
   return fetch(url).then(
    id_list => id_list.json()
  ).then(
    list_data => Promise.all(
      list_data.map(topic => fetch(url +topic.id)
      .then(response =>  response.json()  )
      )
    ) /**end 1st promise.all */

  ) .then(ListNopost =>{
    ListNopost.map( single_entry =>{
      Promise.all( [fetch( url + single_entry.id+ '/posts').then(resp=>resp.json() ) ] )
      .then (posts_data =>{
        single_entry.posts=posts_data[0];
      })
    })
    return ListNopost;
  })
}
```

Isn't promise.all supposed to return only when the promise is resolved?
Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? And help me to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
ListNopost.map( single_entry =>{
   Promise.all( [fetch( url + single_entry.id+ '/posts').then(resp=>resp.json() ) ] )
   .then (posts_data =>{
     single_entry.posts=posts_data[0];
   })
})
return ListNopost;
```

`Promise.all` is never returned so your main promise resolves before the `fetch`s are. Also note that `map` is not a mutator, and has to return a value if you want it to be included in the new array.

Try this:

```
var promises = ListNopost.map(single_entry => {
    return fetch(url + single_entry.id + '/posts')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(posts_data => {
            single_entry.posts = posts_data[0]
            return single_entry
        })
})
return Promise.all(promises)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. You can't imagine how grateful I am.
I have been trying every edit you suggested. Your final edit works perfectly. 

I just needed "posts" as the full array not just the first object so I removed the [0].

Can't thank you enough, thanks again!!